# React child component is passed a function but showing not a function on running.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

The app structure App.js > Shelf.js > Book.js the app.js passes changeShelf function as prop to child shelf which in turn passes it to book. The changeShelf is internaly calling getAll function which is defined in app.js Now when the changeShelf function is called from Book.js it displays an error getALL() is not a function.

```js
import React from 'react'
import Shelf from "./components/Shelf";
import Search from "./Search.js"
import * as BooksAPI from './BooksAPI'
import './App.css'
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import { Route } from "react-router-dom"

class BooksApp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    books: [],
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getBooks()
  }
  getBooks = () => {
    BooksAPI.getAll().then((book) => {
      this.setState({books: book})
    })
  }

  changeShelf(){
    //BooksAPI.update(book, shelf)
   // this.setState({books: book})
    this.getBooks()
  }
  render() {
    
    return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="app">
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
          <div className="list-books">
            <div className="list-books-title">
              <h1>MyReads</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="list-books-content">
              { <Shelf title='Currently Reading' books={this.state.books.filter(book => book.shelf === 'currentlyReading')} key='curentlyReading' changeShelf={this.changeShelf()}/> }
              { <Shelf title='Want to Read' books={this.state.books.filter(book => book.shelf === 'wantToRead')} key='wantToRead' changeShelf={this.changeShelf()} /> }
              { <Shelf title='Read' books={this.state.books.filter(book => book.shelf === 'read')} key='read' changeShelf={this.changeShelf()} /> }
            </div>
            <div className="open-search">
              <Link to="/search">Add a book</Link>
            </div>
          </div> 
          )} />
          <Route path="/search" render={() => (
            <Search />
          )} />
      </div>  
    </BrowserRouter> 
    )
  }
}

export default BooksApp
```

the Shelf.js

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Book from './Book';

export default class Shelf extends Component {
    render() {
      console.log(this.props.changeShelf());
        return ( <div className="bookshelf">
        <h2 className="bookshelf-title">{this.props.title}</h2>
        <div className="bookshelf-books">
          <ol className="books-grid">
              {this.props.books.map((data) => <li><Book book={data} key={data.id} changeShelf={this.props.changeShelf}/> </li> )}
          </ol>
        </div>
      </div>
       )
    }
}
```

the book.js

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import * as BooksAPI from '../BooksAPI'
export default class Book extends Component {
    change = (event) =>{
        BooksAPI.update(this.props.book, event.target.value);
        this.props.changeShelf()
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="book">
                <div className="book-top">
                    <div className="book-cover" style={{ width: 128, height: 188, backgroundImage: `url("${this.props.book.imageLinks.smallThumbnail}")` }}></div>
                    <div className="book-shelf-changer">
                        <select onChange={this.change} value={this.props.book.shelf}>
                            <option value="move" disabled>Move to...</option>
                            <option value="currentlyReading">Currently Reading</option>
                            <option value="wantToRead">Want to Read</option>
                            <option value="read">Read</option>
                            <option value="none">None</option>
                        </select>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div className="book-title">{this.props.book.title}</div>
                <div className="book-authors">{this.props.book.authors[0]}</div>
            </div>
         )
    }
}
```

The complete code base can be found at [git hub link](https://github.com/oreanroy/reactnd-project-myreads-starter)

Comment: In `BooksApp` component, with the initiation of `Shelf` component you have called the `this.changeShelf()` method (`changeShelf={this.changeShelf()}`), instead just pass the reference like `changeShelf={this.changeShelf}`.

Comment: And don't forget to bind `this`

Answer (score 1):

In `App.js` you need to pass `this.changeShelf` function to the `Shelf` component, but now you are passing it invocation.

```
`<div className="list-books-content">
    <Shelf changeShelf={this.changeShelf} />
    <Shelf changeShelf={this.changeShelf} />
    <Shelf changeShelf={this.changeShelf} />
</div>`
```

Comment: But there is  an error that dynamic state change of books do not occur. Page reloading. When i change the shelf.js to this.onChange() dynaic update starts but then the shelf keeps on rerendering except just renedering once.

Answer (score 0):

@Rahul roy with respect to your code 
You would need to bind the `changeShelf` function with the class reference. Or `this.setState` in `getBooks` would throw an error.

See below:

```
<div className="list-books-content">
    <Shelf changeShelf={this.changeShelf.bind(this)} />
    <Shelf changeShelf={this.changeShelf.bind(this)} />
    <Shelf changeShelf={this.changeShelf.bind(this)} />
</div>
```

Comment: On doing this the dynamic rendering of the page and state dynamic state change does not occur.